# hostapd vs netplan: wlan0 not added to bridge at boot

Tags: networking, systemd, netplan, network-bridge, hostapd

Like many people, I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu 20.10 arm64 as a LAN/wifi bridge, using hostapd and netplan.  Everything works fine except that the bridge is not configured correctly when the machine reboots.  `brctl show` shows that `br0` only includes `eth0` and not `wlan0` as it should.  However, running `netplan apply` or `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` after booting adds `wlan0` to the bridge, and then everything else works.

`/var/log/syslog` includes the messages:

```
Jan  1 06:09:25 triangle systemd-networkd[1819]: br0: Link UP
Jan  1 06:09:25 triangle systemd-networkd[1819]: wlan0: Could not join netdev: Device does not allow enslaving to a bridge. Operation not supported
Jan  1 06:09:25 triangle systemd-networkd[1819]: wlan0: Failed
```

and later:

```
Jan  1 06:09:25 triangle systemd-networkd[1819]: wlan0: Link UP
Jan  1 06:09:25 triangle hostapd[1889]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Jan  1 06:09:25 triangle systemd-networkd[1819]: wlan0: Gained carrier
Jan  1 06:09:25 triangle kernel: [   21.926114] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

I think the problem is that when netplan runs at boot, the `wlan0` interface is down, and so netplan fails to add it to  the bridge.  The interface comes up after `hostapd` finishes configuring it, but then it's too late.

I have worked around with `@reboot sleep 5 ; /usr/bin/systemctl restart systemd-networkd` in root's crontab, but is there a proper solution?

The contents of `etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` are:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      wakeonlan: yes

    wlan0:
      optional: true

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth0, wlan0]
      dhcp4: yes
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
```

The contents of `hostapd.conf` are:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
country_code=US
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211h=1
hw_mode=a
channel=161
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=-1
fragm_threshold=-1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wmm_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
eap_server=0
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
wpa=2
wpa_psk_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.wpa_psk
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem,on boot the wlan0 link set to client mode or so...

see the kernel source [br_if.c#L605](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/16fc44d6387e260f4932e9248b985837324705d8/net/bridge/br_if.c#L605) here reject bridge func `br_add_if`

```c
if (dev->priv_flags & IFF_DONT_BRIDGE) {
        NL_SET_ERR_MSG(extack,
                   "Device does not allow enslaving to a bridge");
        return -EOPNOTSUPP;
}
```

and when wlan device register [wireless/core.c#L1305](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e767b3530acbf651593e3d357fe1168a024d8061/net/wireless/core.c#L1305) set the `IFF_DONT_BRIDGE` flag

```c
    if ((wdev->iftype == NL80211_IFTYPE_STATION ||
         wdev->iftype == NL80211_IFTYPE_P2P_CLIENT ||
         wdev->iftype == NL80211_IFTYPE_ADHOC) && !wdev->use_4addr)
        wdev->netdev->priv_flags |= IFF_DONT_BRIDGE;
```

it seems that networkd register wlan0 in module `NL80211_IFTYPE_STATION` on boot.

Fine! Here is my resolutions:

1. Remove wlan0 from netplan, keep networkd unmanaged wlan0 link.
2. Then,you may noticed that hostapd.conf has field like `bridge=br0`,using that to bridge wlan0 to br0.

in your case the config are:

`etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      wakeonlan: yes
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth0]
      dhcp4: yes
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
```

`hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
bridge=br0
logger_syslog=-1
...
```